# How to conveniently specify columns of matrices in a list?

Tags: r, list, matrix

When calculating the matrices column means of a list `ls1`, is there a way to define whole columns (like e.g. column 2) instead of the cells? Intuitively I tried such stuff as `sapply(ls1, "[", [, 2])`,  `sapply(ls1, "[", "[", 2)`, or `sapply(ls1, c("[", "["), 2)` but it won't work.

```
ls1 <- list(matrix(seq(1,16), ncol = 4),
            matrix(seq(17,32), ncol = 4),
            matrix(seq(33,48), ncol = 4))

colMeans(sapply(ls1, "[", 5:8))
# [1]  6.5 22.5 38.5
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply` to get this instead of `sapply` as the arguments are slightly different i.e. few arguments in `lapply` to ensure that the indexing can be done in the order of arguments

```
colMeans(do.call(cbind, lapply(ls1, "[", ,2)))
```

When in doubt, the anonymous function can be helpful

```
colMeans(sapply(ls1, function(x) x[,2]))
```